# Getting a webview to display

Tags: android, webview

Im trying to load a webview with the code below. Im getting red squiggly lines under the id in `R.id.webview`. Any idea what I need to do to fix this. The two solutions recommended are to create field and create constant. But, neither one worked...

Thanks for the help.

```
import android.app.Activity;

import android.os.Bundle;

import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class GreatRacksActivity extends Activity {
  /** Called when the activity is first created. */

   WebView mWebView;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);    
    setContentView(R.layout.main);    
    mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);    
    mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);    
    mWebView.loadUrl("http://mysite.com");
    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new HelloWebViewClient());
}
private class HelloWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {   
    @Override    
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {        
    view.loadUrl(url);        
    return true;    
    }}

}
```

Comment: Is there a WebView(with id webview) in your layout file (main.xml) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to have a webview in your main.xml layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <WebView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/webview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"

        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

You may have missed to have a Id for WebView in your layout.If you share your layout it would help to fix this issue.

Example:
        
        android:id="@+id/webview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />